# Sending an email with TKinter and smtplib

Tags: python, tkinter, smtplib, gmail-imap

I've been trying to write a little email client in python with tkinter, but I'm stuck at the authentication with gmail. It throws this error:

```
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials ci22sm871643ejc.54 - gsmtp')
```

I already double-checked the password several times and have less secure apps activated in my google account, but it still doesn't work. I suspect it's something with TKinter, because it works just fine if I hardcode the values in or use `input()`.

This is my Code (Sorry for the inconsistent formatting, I'm working with another person on this and they choose `"` over `'`):

```
from tkinter import *
import smtplib

main = Tk()
main.title("EMAIL Program")
main.geometry("1000x600")

EMAIL_ADDRESS = 'example@example.com'
PASSWORD = 'EXAMPLE123'

COLLECTOR_EMAIL = 'Receiver'
content = 'Text'
subject = "Subject"

receiver_input = Text(fg='red', bg='gray', width=100,
                      height=1, insertbackground='black', cursor="plus red")
submit_button = Button(text='Send --->', fg='green')
content_input = Text(fg='black', bg='gray', width=100,
                        height=30, insertbackground='black', cursor="circle")

receiver_email = receiver_input.get("1.0", END)
content_message = content_input.get("1.0", END)


def sendemail():
    submit_button.config(fg='red', text="sending...")
    email = EMAIL_ADDRESS  # Your email
    password = PASSWORD  # Your email account password
    send_to_email = receiver_email  # Who you are sending the message to
    message = content_message  # The message in the email

    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)  # Connect to the server
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(email, password)  # Login to the email server
    server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, message)  # Send the email
    server.quit()  # Logout of the email server


def Login():
    def confirm():
        EMAIL_ADRESS = email_input.get(
            "1.0", "end-1c").strip("\n").strip("\t").strip()
        PASSWORD = email_password.get(
            "1.0", "end").strip("\n").strip("\t").strip()
        login_button.destroy()
        email_label = Label(text=f"{EMAIL_ADRESS}")
        email_label.pack()
        login_window.destroy()

    def confirm2():
        receiver_input.pack()
        subject_input = Text(fg='blue', bg='gray', width=100,
                             height=1, insertbackground='black', cursor="dot green red")
        subject_input.pack()
        content_input.pack()
        receiver_input.insert(END, COLLECTOR_EMAIL)
        subject_input.insert(END, subject)
        content_input.insert(END, content)
        submit_button.config(command=sendemail)
        submit_button.pack()

    login_window = Tk()
    login_window.title('Login')
    email_input = Text(login_window, width=30, height=1, fg='blue')
    email_input.pack()
    email_input.insert(END, EMAIL_ADDRESS)
    email_password = Text(login_window, width=30, height=1, fg='red')
    email_password.pack()
    email_password.insert(END, PASSWORD)
    confirm_button = Button(login_window, text='Login',
                            fg='green', command=lambda: [confirm(), confirm2()])
    confirm_button.pack()


login_button = Button(text='Login', fg='blue', command=Login)
login_button.pack()

main.resizable(False, False)
main.mainloop()
```

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Use `print()` to verify if it is what you really want. And also make sure both are the same datatype.

Comment: I think I found the problem. Add `global PASSWORD, EMAIL_ADRESS` to the start of your `confirm` function.

Comment: Why do you use `Text` widget instead of `Entry` widget for single line input?

Comment: It cannot be a problem with Tkinter tho

Comment: @TheLizzard I did that and now I'm getting this error: ```smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'\n': (555, b'5.5.2 Syntax error. s11sm1347279edt.27 - gsmtp')}```